# How do I force a ViewGroup to draw off screen?

Tags: android

I have several LinearLayouts that get filled with downloaded images or text within a ScrollView.  The LinearLayouts have a LayoutAnimation applied to them, so each one "slides" into place when drawn.  Is there a way to force the offscreen LinearLayouts to draw so that by the time the user scrolls to them, the animation has already completed?  I've tried measuring each view like so: (**container** is the ViewGroup)

```
int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST); 
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED); 
container.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight); 
container.layout(0, 0, container.getMeasuredWidth(), container.getMeasuredHeight());
container.requestLayout();
```

But they still won't draw until they appear on screen during scrolling (which normally is fine but the animation makes it.. er, not fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future readers, here's what I ended up doing:  I subclassed LinearLayout and overrode onLayout to only apply animation if the layout is currently on screen at the moment it is populated:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    // only animate if viewgroup is currently on screen
    int[] xy = new int[2];
    this.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    int yPos = xy[1];

    if (yPos < availableScreenHeight && bottom > 200)
    {
        Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.container_slide_down);
        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(slide_down, 0.25f);
        this.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    }
}
```

This actually saves some cycles since I'm not applying animation across the board then removing it from views that don't need it.  (BTW "availableScreenHeight" is just that, and "200" is simply a threshold that I know a populated view will never be smaller than.  Your case may vary.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run the animation why don't you simply remove the animation? The framework will apply the animation because you tells it to.

Also note that none of your code causes a redraw. To draw you need to call invalidate() or draw().

Comment: I want the animation to show on a viewgroup when it gets populated with downloaded data.  This means if it's on screen at that time, you see the animation.  If it's off screen at that time, you don't.  Also the viewgroups can be in any order so I can't assume a certain viewgroup will be on or off screen at any given time.  I figured the easiest way to do it would be to force them to draw when the download is complete, no matter where they are.  As for the second part - I tried container.invalidate() but not luck.  I can't use draw() as I don't have a canvas to reference, just viewgroups.

Comment: Just remove the animation when it's over.

Comment: But Android doesn't start the animation until it's on screen (in my case scrolled into view), so waiting until it's over is too late, because it's already been seen by the user.  The animation doesn't happen off-screen.